# Wordpress /Buddypress issue

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

This is a Wordpress /Buddypress issue-----I have activated wordpress multisite so I can run the main the domain and add many subdomains on the one wp install—But when I added Buddypress to the network admin and network activated, BP did not show (or work) on the subdomain sites—How do I fix it so BP works on all my subdomainS added to the multisite network???----I have done some minor (my limit) coding to get BP to show on te subdomain admin--- can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress was built to transform a regular blog into a social network. There is an option to allow BuddyPress to be accessed from internal blogs in a WordPress Network, however it's limited because it just shares information across sites.

This means all your BuddyPress users will remain the same across internal sites. The way to do this is adding to **wp-config.php**:

```
define('BP_ENABLE_MULTIBLOG', true);
```

Be aware this only allows internal sites to access BuddyPress data using their own URL, for example:

```
http://example.com/members  // Root
http://blog1.example.com/members // Internal site
```

Both of them will display the same information. Now, if what you want is BuddyPress multi-network, then you'd need to install [BP Multi Network plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-multi-network/) which allows every internal site to have their own BuddyPress installation.